# Update existing attribute field. Qgis

Tags: qgis, update

Is it possible by using Field Calculator to Update existing attribute field, ID field, which has many rows with value of 1.

In a way that values of ID field increase top to bottom by value of 1, starting with value 1.

rgrds

Comment: Have you looked at the Sort and Number plugin?

Comment: Top to bottom of what? Drawing order? FID? Else?

Comment: Top to bottom in attribute  table of field called ID , first to the last feature.

Comment: Based on what you have asked, I think you can just use the expression `@row_number`.